# using queue and stack to reverse odd number only in a queue and other functions

Tags: arrays, c, queue, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define type int
#define qsize 40

typedef struct {
    int top;
    type array[qsize];
}stack;
stack *initstack (){
    stack *s=malloc(sizeof(stack)); s->top =0;
    return s;
}
void push(stack *s,type x){
    s->array[s->top++]=x;
}
type pop(stack *s){
    return s->array[--s->top];
}
type isfulls(stack *s){
    return s->top>=qsize;
}
type isemptys(stack *s){
    return !s->top;
}
type peek(stack *s){
    return s->array[s->top-1];
}
//----------------------------------------------------
typedef struct {
    type head;
    type tail;
    int Qnoe;
    type elements[qsize];
}queue;
queue *initqueue(){
    queue *s=malloc(sizeof(queue));
    s->Qnoe=0;  s->head=0;  s->tail=-1;
    return s;
}
void enqueue(queue *s,type e){
    s->elements[++s->tail%qsize]=e; s->Qnoe++;
}
type dequeue(queue *s){
    type temp=s->elements[s->head++%qsize];
    s->Qnoe--; return temp;
}
int isempty(queue *s){
    return !s->Qnoe;
}
int isfull(queue *s){
    return s->Qnoe==qsize;
}
type gethead(queue *s){
    return s->elements[s->head];
}
type gettail(queue *s){
    return s->elements[s->tail];
}

void display(queue *s){   ///used just to display the functions
    queue *temp=initqueue();
    while(!isempty(s)){
        type x=dequeue(s);
        printf("%d      ",x);
        enqueue(temp,x);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    while(!isempty(temp)) enqueue(s,dequeue(temp));
}
int maxvalue(queue *s){
    type max,head;
    queue *temp=initqueue();if(!isempty(s)) {enqueue(temp,dequeue(s)); max=gethead(s);}
    while (!isempty(s)){
        head=gethead(s);
        if(max<head) max=head;
        enqueue(temp,dequeue(s));
    }
    while(!isempty(temp)) enqueue(s,dequeue(temp));
    return max;
}
void swap(queue *s){
    type head=gethead(s),tail=gettail(s);int i=0,j=1;
    queue *temp=initqueue();
    while(!isempty(s)) {i++; enqueue(temp,dequeue(s));}
    dequeue(temp); enqueue(s,tail); ;
    while(!isempty(temp)){
        if(j++==i-1) {enqueue(s,head); break;}
        else {enqueue(s,dequeue(temp));}
    } free(temp);
}
void insert(queue *s,type e,int index){
    queue *temp=initqueue(); int i=1;
    while(!isempty(s)){
        if(index==i++) {enqueue(temp,e); dequeue(s);}
        else enqueue(temp,dequeue(s));
    }
    while(!isempty(temp)) enqueue(s,dequeue(temp));
}
void revercOdd(queue *s){
    queue *tempq=initqueue();
    stack *temps=initstack();
    while(!isempty(s)){
        if(gethead(s)%2){push(temps,dequeue(s)); enqueue(tempq,1);}
        else enqueue(tempq,dequeue(s));
    }
    while(!isempty(tempq)){
        if(gethead(tempq)==1){enqueue(s,pop(temps)); dequeue(tempq);}
        else enqueue(s,dequeue(tempq));
    }
}


int main()
{
    queue *s=initqueue();
    enqueue(s,5);
    enqueue(s,8);
    enqueue(s,3);
    enqueue(s,2);
    enqueue(s,1);
    enqueue(s,0);
    enqueue(s,112);
    printf("the queue: \n");
    display(s);
    printf("max value in queue : %d\n\n",maxvalue(s));
    swap(s);
    printf("the queue after swapping the head and tail: \n");
    display(s);
    printf("\nthe queue: \n");
    display(s);
    type e,index;
    printf("enter he value of the elemnt and the index: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&e,&index);
    insert(s,e,index);
    printf("the queue after inserting %d in the index %d:  \n",e,index);
    display(s);
    printf("\nthe queue: \n");
    display(s);
    revercOdd(s);
    printf("the queue after reversing odd number only: \n");
    display(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I made 4 functions 1 to get the max element in the queue 1 to get swap the head and tail of the queue 1 to take an element and index and put it in that index in the queue and 1 to reverse odd numbers only in a queue using queue and stack and a function to display the element of a given queue to check results and in the main, I check the outputs of every function work on its own, but when I use them together the last display shows the garbage element in the queue:

Comment: Side note: As soon as you change `type` e.g. to `char*` or some struct your `queue` breaks! You should change `head` and `tail` to some integral type, recommending `size_t` (`stddef.h`).

Comment: `maxValue` has a memory leak as you never `free(temp)`.

Comment: Please [edit] and show s simple example of input along with expectd vs. actual output.

Comment: Why would you need those temporaries at all? All operations can be done without, e.g. `display`: `if(head < tail) { for(size_t i = head; i < tail; ++i) { /*print elements[i]*/ } } else { /* print elements from tail to qsize, then from 0 to tail */ }` – same iteration to find the maximum. Insertion: Start at `head + index` (consider overflowing `qsize`!), then iterate until end of queue reached, swapping `elements[i]` and `e`.

Comment: `++s->tail%qsize` will, if you have enough operations, overflow after reaching `INT_MAX` (`SIZE_MAX`, if you follow my recommendation) – if now `SIZE_MAX + 1` is *not* a multiple of `qsize` then you restart at the wrong position! Better: `tail = (tail + 1) %  qsize; elements[tail]` – analogously: `elements[head]; head = (head + 1) % qsize;`.

Comment: Reversing odd numbers only: Again do without another queue, instead: Start at both head and tail - 1, iterate from head forwards and tail backwards (and consider leaving array bounds, then re-starting at the other end!) until you reach an odd number for each, then swap these directly and continue this way until both head and tail iterators meet or overtake one another.